# Perform floor or ceil on specific column of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

In my program, I have a 2D numpy array detailing a set of 3 dimensional coordinates. For example the array named *a*:

```
[
 [-72.86, -13.56, 68.45],
 [-58.31, -14.98, 54.76],
 [29.16, 7.23, -27.38]
]
```

What I want to do is then create a copy of this array, *b*, which may have the first column floored and the last two rounded up. I would have an array for each of the 8 possibilities.

To do this I need to be able to perform np.floor() and np.ceil() to individual columns. So far I've come up with the following attempt:

```
b = np.floor(a[:,0])
b = np.ceil(b[:,1])
b = np.ceil(b[:,2])
```

I apologise if the answer is obvious. I'm fairly new to python and numpy and have gotten myself a bit confused. Any help would be much appreciated :).

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: `b = np.c_[np.floor(a[:,0]), np.ceil(a[:,[1,2]])]`, IIUC. Your question is unclear, because you reassign multiple times to *b* and slice columns from *b* that don't exist.